# How to calculate the ratio using two hashmaps in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I am building a program that decides which group of people will survive and trace all the attributes. Therefore, I use one `ArrayList` to save the survived attributes, and another save the total attributes for the coming survival ratio calculation.

I've confirmed that my attributes are saved correctly, but I don't know what's wrong with my hashmap code. It showed everything `0.00`. My idea is to find the frequency of each attribute, and compute the ratio based on its frequency and the key. Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

```
    Map<Object, Double> totalCounts = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Object, Double> surviveCounts = new HashMap<>();

    //put total characteristics in the map
   for (Object element : total) {
       if (totalCounts.containsKey(element)) {
           totalCounts.put(element, totalCounts.get(element) + (double) 1);
       } else {
           totalCounts.put(element,(double) 1);
       }

    }
    //put survived characteristics in the map
   for (Object survive : survival) {
       if (surviveCounts.containsKey(survive)) {
           surviveCounts.put (survive, surviveCounts.get(survive) + (double) 1);
       } else {
           surviveCounts.put(survive, (double) 1);
       }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entrySurvive : surviveCounts.entrySet()) {

        Object surviveKey = entrySurvive.getKey();
        Double surviveValue = entrySurvive.getValue();

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entryTotal : totalCounts.entrySet()) {

            Object totalKey = entryTotal.getKey();
            Double totalValue = entryTotal.getValue();

            if (totalKey.equals(surviveKey)) {
                double percent = surviveValue / totalValue;
                surviveData.put(surviveKey, percent);
            } else {
                surviveData.put(totalKey, (double) 0);
            }
        }
    }
    //print out the ratio
    surviveData.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((k1, k2) -> -k1.getValue().compareTo(k2.getValue()))
            .forEach(k -> System.out.println(k.getKey().toString().toLowerCase() + ": " +String.format("%.2f", k.getValue())));
```

Comment: Can you check inside ```if (totalKey.equals(surviveKey))```, value of ```surviveValue ``` and ```totalValue``` are correct?

Comment: is correct. It should be the code in the `else` statement that lead to `0.00`, but I am still trying to fix this. Thank you, @NitinSinghal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using the nested for loop, there is 100% that `totalKey` and `surviveKey` will be different. Thus:

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entrySurvive : surviveCounts.entrySet()) {

    Object surviveKey = entrySurvive.getKey();
    Double surviveValue = entrySurvive.getValue();

    for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entryTotal : totalCounts.entrySet()) {

        Object totalKey = entryTotal.getKey();
        Double totalValue = entryTotal.getValue();

        if (totalKey.equals(surviveKey)) {
            double percent = surviveValue / totalValue;
            surviveData.put(surviveKey, percent);
        } else {
            //will lead to all attributes' ratio 0.00
            surviveData.put(totalKey, (double) 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The correct way to put those dead people is:

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entrySurvive : surviveCounts.entrySet()) {

        Object surviveKey = entrySurvive.getKey();
        double surviveValue = entrySurvive.getValue();

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entryTotal : totalCounts.entrySet()) {

            Object totalKey = entryTotal.getKey();
            double totalValue = entryTotal.getValue();

            if (totalKey.equals(surviveKey)) {
                double percent = surviveValue / totalValue;
                surviveData.put(surviveKey, percent);
            }
        }
    }

    // if the surviveCounts' keys aren't in the totalCount's key
    // it means they're not even survive once
    for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entryTotal : totalCounts.entrySet()) {
        Object totalKey = entryTotal.getKey();

        if (!surviveCounts.containsKey(entryTotal.getKey())) {
            surviveData.put(totalKey, (double) 0);               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update if `surviceKey is equal to totalKey`

```
       for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entrySurvive : surviveCounts.entrySet()) {
            Object surviveKey = entrySurvive.getKey();
            Double surviveValue = entrySurvive.getValue();

            for (Map.Entry<Object, Double> entryTotal : totalCounts.entrySet()) {

                Object totalKey = entryTotal.getKey();
                Double totalValue = entryTotal.getValue();

                if (totalKey.equals(surviveKey)) {
                    double percent = surviveValue / totalValue;
                    surviveData.put(surviveKey, percent);
                }
            }
        }
```

Or you can just write,

```
Map<Object, Double> surviveData = surviveCounts.keySet().stream()
                .filter(totalCounts::containsKey)
                .collect(
Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k->surviveCounts.get(k)/totalCounts.get(k)));
```

Comment: Can you share some sample entries, I can try debugging

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan ```surviceKey``` and ```totalKey``` both are objects, how can you compare them with ```==```

Comment: That was typo, I intend to use equals only (refer code)

Comment: @Woden I have updated my answer with streams, can you try that too?

Comment: Thank you, sir. but you may not see the request that I want to trace not only the value of survival attributes, but also those who never survive.